# How can I set the CSS class only to the parent and not its children in Quill?

Tags: jquery, css, parent-child, quill, ngx-quill

I'm using Quill Editor inside an Angular project. My problem is that when I set a custom class to an element I get this result:

`<p class=custom-class>testesetsetset</p>`

When I try to add another tag, Quill sets the same class to its children. This is what I got:

`<p class=custom-class> testes <strong class=custom-class>ets</strong> etset</p>`

Is it possible instead to achieve this result, and not set the class to its children?

`<p class=custom-class> testes <strong>ets</strong> etset</p>`

A Big Thanks to who will help!!

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show us the Angular code you describe.